# SQLHelper and DAL

Tags: vb.net

Do developers still use [SQLHelper.vb](https://appsimplicity.googlecode.com/svn-history/r217/MetaDataExtractor/SchemaDiscovery/AppSimplicity.SchemaDiscovery.Providers/SQLServer/DataAccess/SQLHelper.vb) to deal with their data access logic?  Is there a similar class available for connections to an Oracle database? I have searched for this Oracle class online but I cannot find it.  For example, I came accross [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/272556.aspx/1).

I realise that there are alternative DAL solutions like NHibernate, but really what I am looking for is a place to encapsulate the data access logic.

Comment: @SLaks, I have updated the question.  The classes in the application I am developing are not very well written according to SOLID principles.  Therefore at the moment I am looking for a solution to encapsulate the Data Access Logic.  At a later date when I have had time to refactor the code, I may incorporate an ORM.

Comment: The application I am developing connects to many databases including SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: @w0051977: [dotConnect Universal](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/universal/)?